# Downgrade 2sxc from 9.32 to 9.14

Tags: 2sxc

Is there a procedure to follow to downgrade 2sxc?  We are currently on 9.32 and would like to downgrade to 9.14 due to a critical feature not working properly for us on 9.32.

Installing 9.14 would fail since we have 9.32 installed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of 2sxc allow downgrades, but I believe that there were some breaking changes in the data model between 9.14 and 9.32 so I think a downgrade will be very risky if not impossible.

Best to post the issue and if it's critical, maybe assist in fixing it asap.